# How to auto increment by +1 a specific number of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have a MySQL table with a column which I want to auto increment by +1 value for a specific number of rows (where id_sample='2'). What do you think, I can archive this by a single query, or I need to update row by row :(.
A short preview of my table is:

```
+----------+----------+---------+
| id       | id_sample| degrees |
+----------+----------+---------+
| 361      |    2     |    0    |
| 362      |    2     |    0    |
| 363      |    2     |    0    |
| 364      |    2     |    0    |
| 365      |    2     |    0    |
| 366      |    2     |    0    |
| ...      |  ....    |   ....  |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I want to archive this:

```
+----------+----------+---------+
| id       | id_sample| degrees |
+----------+----------+---------+
| 361      |    2     |    1    |
| 362      |    2     |    2    |
| 363      |    2     |    3    |
| 364      |    2     |    4    |
| 365      |    2     |    5    |
| 366      |    2     |    6    |
| ...      |  ....    |   ....  |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I tried this query (see bellow) but I got an increment for all rows: with the corresponding id_sample='2':

```
UPDATE myTable SET degrees=degrees+1 WHERE id_sample='2';
```

Comment: @javaL - reading what someone posted will get you a long way in this industry. He **wrote** that his code did not do what he needed.

Comment: @javaL - I don't understand whether you're just clueless or a simpleton, what's the point in telling someone their code won't work if the person knows that and mentions that?

Comment: @N.B. i gave the reason

Comment: @javaL - you might reconsider posting comments until you actually read and understand question in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use variables. Here is a solution:

```
SET @rownum=0;
UPDATE myTable SET degrees=(@rownum:=@rownum+1) WHERE id_sample='2';
```

Inspired by this: [Display Rownum issue MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460300/display-rownum-issue-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for all. You saved me for a lot of time. I accept your answer soon!

Answer (score 1):

```
Update mytable a set a.degrees = (select nvl(max(b.degree),0)+1 from mytable b where a.id=b.id and b.id_sample=2);
```